# Querying associations with enum in Grails where query

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a query issue with Grails 3.2.6 and I created a sample project to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/sarbogast/QueryTest

In this project I have 3 entities: Project has many TodoLists, that in turn have many Todos. Todos can also be directly associated to projects without going through TodoList. So a Todo either has a parent Project, or a parent TodoList, but never both at the same time.

Now in my controller I would like to load all todos that are associated to a Project of a given type, either directly or indirectly, where type is an enum.

Here is the code of the controller action:

```
def index(Integer max, String projectType) {
    def type = projectType ? ProjectType.valueOf(projectType) : null
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    if(type) {
        def todoQuery = Todo.where {
            parentProject.type == type || parentList.parentProject.type == type
        }
        respond todoQuery.list(params), model: [todoCount: todoQuery.count()]
    } else {
        respond Todo.list(params), model:[todoCount: Todo.count()]
    }
}
```

If I don't specify a type, it correctly returns all the instances I created in BootStrap. But if I specify a project type in the query, the result list is empty.

There seems to be something wrong with my query but I can't figure out what.

Note that I have seen examples in Criteria queries with specified JOINs and what not, but then I don't know how to reuse the same query for the count.

EDIT: Here are the SQL statements that are logged when I GET `http://localhost:8080/todo?projectType=ENGINEERING`:

```
select count(*) as y0_ from todo this_ inner join todo_list parentlist2_ on this_.parent_list_id=parentlist2_.id inner join project parentproj1_ on this_.parent_project_id=parentproj1_.id where ((parentproj1_.type=?) or ((parentproj1_.type=?))) limit ?
select this_.id as id1_1_2_, this_.version as version2_1_2_, this_.parent_list_id as parent_l3_1_2_, this_.parent_project_id as parent_p4_1_2_, this_.task as task5_1_2_, parentlist2_.id as id1_2_0_, parentlist2_.version as version2_2_0_, parentlist2_.parent_project_id as parent_p3_2_0_, parentlist2_.title as title4_2_0_, parentproj1_.id as id1_0_1_, parentproj1_.version as version2_0_1_, parentproj1_.name as name3_0_1_, parentproj1_.type as type4_0_1_ from todo this_ inner join todo_list parentlist2_ on this_.parent_list_id=parentlist2_.id inner join project parentproj1_ on this_.parent_project_id=parentproj1_.id where ((parentproj1_.type=?) or ((parentproj1_.type=?))) limit ?
```

Comment: your enums have no value keys  `ProjectType."${projectType}"` vs `ProjectType.valueOf(projectType)` does that change behaviour ?

Comment: Log your sql and inspect

Comment: @vahid With a breakpoint, I can check that the type variable is correctly initialized with the right enum constant. valueOf() correctly converts a String into the corresponding enum constant.

Comment: @JamesKleeh I just did and I don't understand what it does. I added the 3 logged SQL statements that correspond to one call of this action in the original question.

Comment: You have a problem obscuring the actual question: when you do just `where { list.project.type == type }` it returns all the rows. If you rename list in your todo with something else, it is correctly filtering with that where.

Comment: As to your actual problem, you have todos 1, 2, 3 that are linked to a list while 4, 5 are linked to a project. When you do your where, it is creating an inner join on both tables but they are mutually exclusive. The solution to that would normally be to use an outer join but I have no idea how to do that in GORM Where clause.

Comment: I tried a few things but I think it's not possible to outer join with a GORM where clause.

Comment: And what type do you specify for your enum's valueOf? java.lang.String?

Comment: You can specify an outer join in a criteria query

Comment: @AntonHlinisty The parameter passed to valueOf is a String and I get an enum constant back. So `ProjectType.valueOf("ENGINEERING")==ProjectType.ENGINEERING`

Comment: @JamesKleeh Any documentation that shows how to do this? Because I couldn't find any mention of `createAlias()` (which I guess is used to specify outer joins) in either GORM or Grails doc. And here I need to do 2 joins on one side of the query.

Comment: Google "grails createAlias"...